# How to make it by css hover?

Tags: css

Take a look at the image. First one is hover. How to make such gradient hover effects with the gradient background?
Here's the HTML code- https://github.com/itsumrat/olivia/blob/master/index.html#L127
Here's SCSS code-
https://github.com/itsumrat/olivia/blob/master/assets/src/scss/components/_feature.scss
[image]

Comment: please give us the code that you tried?

Comment: Check out this link. https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: You would do it the exact same way as if it wasn't on hover, then put `:hover` on the selector.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. If this is a screenshot from another website, then just press F12 and copy their CSS.

Comment: If you can show us what you've tried so far, we can offer help and input to move you in the right direction.

Comment: Here's the HTML code- https://github.com/itsumrat/olivia/blob/master/index.html#L127
Here's SCSS code-
https://github.com/itsumrat/olivia/blob/master/assets/src/scss/components/_feature.scss

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple Background Change on Hover:

```
#yourbutton:hover {
    background: linear-gradient: ....;
}
```

Maybe there's a div in the button with a small white border around. You could Effect the color of that div to have the same result as in the image.

Comment: How can you make gradient colored circle by this code and space between background and border?
See my code.
Here's the HTML code- https://github.com/itsumrat/olivia/blob/master/index.html#L127
Here's SCSS code-
https://github.com/itsumrat/olivia/blob/master/assets/src/scss/components/_feature.scss